# Click item timing out selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Can anyone please explain to me why this is timing out
I am trying to click a button on a webpage that opens a little pop-up window.

This is the code I am using

```
DotXpath='//*[@id="clipboardenabled"]/div/pv-accounts-actions-manager/pv-accounts/pv-accounts-splitter/cyb-splitter/div/div[1]/pv-accounts-grid/cyb-server-data-table/div[1]/ag-grid-angular/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/cyb-actions-col/div/cyb-more-items-trigger-action-menu/cyb-floating-container/div/span/span/cyb-more-items-trigger/button/span'

Submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,DotXpath)))
Submit.click()
```

Don't know if it'll help but here is the code from developer tools

[image]

I'm very new to selenium so help would be greatly appreciated

########################################

---------------------------EDIT--------------------------

#######################################

It seems the button is not visible at first (I am trying to click the ellipse)
[image]

But once I hover over a column in the table it becomes visible

[image]

So I attempted to simulate the hover using the below code

```
xpath='//*[@id="clipboardenabled"]/div/pv-accounts-actions-manager/pv-accounts/pv-accounts-splitter/cyb-splitter/div/div[1]/pv-accounts-grid/cyb-server-data-table/div[1]/ag-grid-angular/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]'
elem = driver.find_element("xpath", xpath)
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elem)
hover.perform()
```

Where I am attempting to hover over the Access Request column
[image]

But the `find_element()` cant find the element. Error below

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="clipboardenabled"]/div/pv-accounts-actions-manager/pv-accounts/pv-accounts-splitter/cyb-splitter/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNhSe.png)/pv-accounts-grid/cyb-server-data-table/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNhSe.png)/ag-grid-angular/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cTYZ.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNhSe.png)/div[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6hiE.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNhSe.png)/div/div/div/div/i"}

Comment: Please share all your code including the URL of the page you are working on or at least entire XML of it as a text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following `xpath` to identify the element.

```
//button[@aria-label='more items']
```

code:

```
DotXpath="//button[@aria-label='more items']"
Submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,DotXpath)))
Submit.click()
```

If you still getting timeout error. May be for couple of reasons.

1.element may not be visible on the page. you need to either scroll to page to make it visible and then click or you can use javascript executor to click.

```
Submit=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='more items']"))) 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Submit)
```

---

2.The element may present inside an iframe. if that so you need to switch to iframe first, then able to click on the element.

```
 driver.switch_to.frame("framename")
 DotXpath="//button[@aria-label='more items']"
 Submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,DotXpath)))
 Submit.click()
```

Comment: Thank you!
It seems like you are right the element might not be visible on the page
Please have a look at my edits on the post for a more detailed explanation.
I'm still not sure how to fix this

Comment: @Susan-l3p : Have you tried all the solutions, I have provided.

Comment: Yes I have tried all 3 
They either time out or fail because it can't find the element

Comment: @Susan-l3p : In that case I need page url to investigate or full page html?

Comment: apologies, I just had the frame id wrong.
The script is working now.
Thank you so much